# How to use index of type string in index compare

Tags: typescript

I have a comparing method of two arrays like this:

```
 const filteredData = lowerCustomerCSVData && lowerCustomerCSVData.map((data: CustomerData) => {
    const u: FilteredData = {};
    isSelected.forEach((key: string) => {
        u[key] = data[key];
    });
    return u;
});
```

where the `lowerCustomerCSVData` is an array of objects of mixed types, and `CustomerData` is
interface like this:

```
interface CustomerData {
    firstname: string | number | undefined,
    lastname: string | number | undefined,
    age: string | number | undefined,
    dobd: string | number | undefined,
    ct: string | number | undefined,
    dobm: string | number | undefined,
    doby: string | number | undefined,
    gen: string | number | undefined,
    country: string | number | undefined,
    zip: string | number | undefined,
    phone: string | number | undefined,
    state: string | number | undefined,
}
```

and the `FilteredData` is an interface like this:

```
interface FilteredData {
    [key: string]: string | number;
}
```

I'm getting an error message saying that I don't have an index signature with a parameter of type 'string' on type 'CustomerData'. And this error appeared on `data[key]` in my comparing method. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding this line to `CustomerData` interface

```
[key: string]: string | number | undefined
```